# How do I un-tame a wolf through NBT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On any given server, the need to untame a wolf (without killing it) for whatever reason arises eventually.

However, upon attempting to do this on my own test server with the below command, nothing happened. The wolf was still tame to me, and would refuse to let go.

```
/entitydata @e[type=Wolf,r=5] {Owner:,OwnerUUID:}
```

What am  I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a change in owner to be considered, the `OwnerUUID` tag must not have an empty value. However, providing it a correctly-formatted UUID will cause it to be tamed to whoever has that UUID (even if nonexistent). If you provide it with an invalid format, it will instead become wild as though it were never tamed:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Wolf,r=5] {OwnerUUID:"blah"}
```

The `Owner` tag is deprecated, and is ignored if `OwnerUUID` is specified.